# Safely unwrapping result of filtering array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm using a textField for user to enter text to filter out specific comments based on the search text. I hate force unwrapping this but `starts(with: )` is exactly what I need to filter by. Is there a way to safely unwrap this without looping through each item in array? Thanks a lot!

```
self.dataSourceChainArray = tempArr.filter{ 
    ($0.startingComment?.attributeName?.starts(with: theString))!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could avoid the force-unwrap by using the nil-coalescing operator.

```
self.dataSourceChainArray = tempArr.filter{ 
    $0.startingComment?.attributeName?.starts(with: theString) ?? false
}
```

Change `false` to `true` if that better suits your needs.

Comment: Perfect, nice and clean. Thanks for the help!